# Refactoring imports across project files

Tags: javascript, refactoring, automated-refactoring

So currently we have a lot of imports in our app that look like:

```
import { withQuery } from "my-external-package"
```

or

```
import { withQuery, withUpsert } from "my-external-package"
```

and we would like to refactor these imports to come from a local file:

```
import { withQuery } from "../../somelocalfile.js"
```

I need the relative path to be computed correctly for nesting. Also the original imports might have other components coming, ex.

```
import { somefunc, withQuery, someotherfunc } from "my-external-package"
```

I am not too familiar with refactoring tools and projects. Let me know if you need any more info.